# Insufficient Code Coverage for Batch Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage

```
global class EmailNotificationBatch implements Database.batchable<sObject>,Schedulable,Database.Stateful
{

    /* Getting data from the account */
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator('select name,Owner.Name,Budget_planning_start_month__c,Owner.Email from Account WHERE isTwoMonthPrior__c =true AND isTwoMonthPriorStatus__c =false');
    }
    /*sending the mail to account manager   */
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope)
    {
        List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > mailList = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > (); 

        for(Account ac:scope){

            List < String > toAddresses = new List < String > ();
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
           // toAddresses.add(ac.Owner.Email);
            toAddresses.add('varun.sharma94@gmail.com');
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            mail.setSubject('Pitching For Budget Planning Start Month');
            String messageBody = '<html><body>Hello ' + ac.Owner.Name  + ',<br> <br> Your Account ' + ac.Name +' is going to start budgeting for this year on ' +ac.Budget_planning_start_month__c.format() +'  .You can plan pitching to the customer accordingly.<br></body></html>';
            mail.setHtmlBody(messageBody);
            mailList.add(mail);
            ac.isTwoMonthPriorStatus__c=true;
        }
        update scope;
        Messaging.sendEmail(mailList); 

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 

    }
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {        
        EmailNotificationBatch snInstance = new EmailNotificationBatch();
        ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(snInstance);
    } 
}
```

---

```
@isTest
public class EmailNotificationBatchTest {

    static testmethod void executeTest(){
        Account newAcc = new Account();
        newAcc.name='Test';
        insert newAcc;

    }
    static testmethod void schedulerTest() {
        Test.startTest();
        EmailNotificationBatch sh1 = new EmailNotificationBatch();
        String sch = '0 0 23 * * ?';
        system.schedule('EmailNotificationBatch Check', sch, sh1); 
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

In this test class I have coverage of 30%. I am stuck in covering the `SingleMessaging` in `execute` method.

Comment: and don't forget the asserts ...code coverage testing _per se_ is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

1) So first issue you only test the scheduler but you want to also test the batch  run. 2) you want to increase code coverage

So for first issue, call the batch, otherwise stoptest just runs your scheudlable job and queues up your batch for a later that won't ever come

```
static testmethod void batchText() {
    Test.startTest();
    Database.executeBatch(new EmailNotificationBatch());
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

So now you need code coverage, which makes sense there isn't going to be any data for that batch to run, so add some

```
static testmethod void batchText() {
    // insert lots of account for your batch class to use
    Test.startTest();
    Database.executeBatch(new EmailNotificationBatch());
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

That'll get most of the logic code, but want about the send email? Well that all works fine except for the ending of it, and you can cheat there, so. the only real issues is calling send emails which often fails in sandboxes, so put the other option (just use null) in a ternary branch, so regardless of how you approach it you get the code coverage.

```
if (Test.isRnningTest() ? null : Messaging.sendEmail(mailList));
```

Comment: static testmethod void batchText() {
        Test.startTest();
        Account newAcc = new Account();
        newAcc.name='Test';
        newAcc.Country__c ='TBD';
        insert newAcc;
        Database.executeBatch(new EmailNotificationBatch());
        Test.stopTest();
    }.

Comment: I have used this but still the  coverage have not been increased.

Comment: @Abhishek in your start method you have two filters on the account table, you'll need to make sure you're account meets those criteria otherwise they'll be no records for the batch to process